# Has Ajaxsubmit been renamed in Stencil from Blueprint? I need to add multiple sizes of product with seperate quantity boxes to cart on BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

TLDR: has the ajaxsubmit url parameter been renamed in Stencil, or is there a better way to add multiple sizes with different quantities to the cart quickly?

I need to have separate quantity boxes for each size of a product so customers can order for sports teams. I have been able to make this format appear on the frontend by using this code in templates/components/products/set-select.html:

```
{{#if display_name '==' 'Size'}}
    {{#each values}}
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <input class="size-quantity" type="tel" name="{{id}}">    
    {{/each}}
    <script>
        sizeattributeid = {{id}};
    </script>
{{/if}}
```

I have also created a separate 'Add Sizes to Cart' button that fires a function looping through each `.size-quantity` box to collect the '`name`' and '`val`' of each one so I can submit it to the cart.

My first thought was to do this via an ajax request with jQuery like this:

```
 productid = jQuery('input[name="product_id"]').val();


    jQuery('.size-quantity').each(function() {
        qty_value = jQuery(this).val();
        sizeattributevalue = jQuery(this).attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: cartUrl+'?action=add&amp;product_id='+productid+'&amp;qty[]=qty_value&amp;attribute['+sizeattributeid+']='+sizeattributevalue+'&amp;ajaxsubmit=1&amp;fastcart=1',
            success: function(data) {
                        //parse bigcommerce html reponse
                        var obj = JSON.parse($(data).html());
                        //success property = true if item was added successfully
                       if (obj.success) {
                           console.log('yay!');
                        } else {
                           console.log('fail!');
                        } 
                 }
            }); 
     });
```

And I have been able to get the crafted URL to add a product to the cart if I paste the generated url into the browser...but I have not been able to with ajax. It seems the ajaxsubmit part of their code does not work with Stencil the way that it worked with Blueprint.

Has this code been renamed? My only alternative to this has been to hide the select box for size and the box for quantity, and then on submit loop through each size and have the quantity box fill in with the desired quantity and submit the form...but that is slow and the only way I've been able to get that to work is by spacing out my requests 600ms at a time, an unacceptable wait.